# Force Xcode to ALWAYS copy resources folder on build

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode5

OK, the situation is rather simple (though un-solvable...):

- I have a folder-reference, in my Xcode project, mostly with HTML/JS/CSS resources, changing frequently, using an external editor
- I want this particular folder re-copied to the app bundle, for *every* build, without having to clean the project (the project is HUGE so unnecessarily re-compiling is quite a waste of time)

I tried adding a custom Build Phase (run script), either by `touch`ing the folder, or by creating a dummy file in the resources folder and deleting it afterwards, but none of that worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What finally worked for me :**

- Create a "Run" Build Script phase, *before* `Copy Bundle Resources`
- Set the script as follows:

  ```
  find "${SRCROOT}/path/to/resources/$1" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 touch
  ```

Comment: Why not write a script that does the copying for you?

Comment: @trojanfoe Well, the funny thing is I thought of this (obvious) solution, a couple of minutes after solving it (and having struggled  with that stupid thing, for like 2 hours...)! lol. :-)

Comment: The only issue with that is you need to use the correct Xcode-provided environment variables in order for it to work in both normal and archive builds.  Not trivial, however I have written scripts in the past that signed and copied files, so it's certainly possible :)

Comment: I use a sophisticated `rsync` script which copies a "resource folder" as is. However, Xcode fails to correctly "sync" the resources on the simulator and device: for example, resource files which have been deleted in a build will not be deleted from the device if they exist from the previous build. You have to delete the app from the device to fix this error. There is no workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested that if you change the last modification date of a file to now, Xcode will build the newer file in the bundle.

New a new run script build phase with your script, the script must run before `Copy Bundle Resources`.

[image]

In the script, enumerate every resource file and use `touch -m filename`.

Comment: Thanks! Close but still not working for me. I'm posting what finally **did** work..